# VSTest.Console.exe: no test results file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Using the following command, I run C++ unit tests created for Microsoft Native Unit Test Framework using the test console (VSTest.Console.exe):

```
VSTest.Console.exe MyTests.dll /ResultsDirectory:TestResults
```

The test output in the console looks like this:

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
  Passed ToString_Test [< 1 ms]

Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 1
     Passed: 1
 Total time: 0.6480 Seconds
```

The TestResults directory is created but it is empty. What is missing for me to get a JUnit xml results file for jenkins?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did jenkins MSTest plugin work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use command  /logger:trx

```
VSTest.Console.exe MyTests.dll /ResultsDirectory:TestResults /logger:trx
```

> /Logger:[uri/friendlyname]    [;LogFileName=]
>
> Specify a logger for test results. Specify the parameter multiple
> times to enable multiple loggers.
>
> Example: To log results into a Visual Studio Test Results File (TRX),
> use /Logger:trx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need a Test report XML for jenkins.

Comment: Conversion tool is needed. Have you tried the MSTest plugin?